# Camera in 3D Viewport Movement issue

Tags: 3d-view, camera

1 week into using blender. I'm having a bit of an issue with a "dodgey" 3D viewport camera.

Its kinda going mental, sometimes when i move the mouse around i get a straight forwards pan and tilt (which is great) but then sometimes i'm having this night mare of a control issue where i start orbiting things.

I've done a lot of googling around the subject and have turned on and off the "lock object" option, played around with "Auto Depth" and other ideas in the Preferences > Navigation options.

I just cant quite get it to play nice!

Heres a video to show what its doing (1mins) - https://youtu.be/Yc4FLM5s-ac

If anyone has any ideas, i'd be really appreciated as its putting a bit of a dampner on things

Sam

Comment: Have you tried resetting to factory setting? You can make a new file with factory settings, save those preferences, and load your original project: Open... -> Click on your project once -> Click the gear -> Deselect "Load UI"